# Exclude documents from aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get a filtered result set from my index.

```
{"group_id": 123, "type" : 1},
{"group_id": 123, "type" : 3},
{"group_id": 123, "type" : 2},
{"group_id": 423, "type" : 3},
{"group_id": 423, "type" : 1},
{"group_id": 231, "type" : 1}
```

Now I want to get all documents but exclude the ones with group_id that contains type = 2. So, in this case, I want to get all documents with group_id = 423 and group_id = 231, but exclude all documents with group_id = 123.

I was experimenting with filtered bool query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but that only excludes one document.

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: I doubt if this can be done using Elasticsearch in a single search request. Are you open to a solution that requires two Elasticsearch search requests to achieve what you want?

Comment: Sure I am, that was the first idea that came to my mind, but I started wondering whether it is possible to somehow do it with one request.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using two Elasticsearch search requests:

First, get all values of "group_id" for which corresponding value of "type" is 2. You need to use [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) for this.

```
POST <index name>/<type name>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "type": 2
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_ids_type_2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "group_id",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Save the list of values of "group_id" fields received from the above request.

Now, use a query with [`must_not`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) filter to get all documents such that the value of their "group_id" is not present in the list obtained above. You need to use [Terms Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) here.

```
POST <index name>/<type name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "group_id": [
              "123"                 <-- Replace this with a comma separated list of all group_id values received from first search request
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```